# Use Preferences to get SharedPreferences

Tags: android, preferences, sharedpreferences

I had been using shared preferences to store some user values....
but when the nos of preferences started increasing. So i decided to use PreferenceActivity.

My problem is i want my prefeneceActivity to use my earlier sharedpreferences.
Have already done the code for shared prefeneceActivity but just couldn't get option to use sharedpreferences.

Comment: I'm still new at this, but couldn't you do a one off activity that transferes the SharedPreferences to PreferenceActivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
SharedPreferences pref= Context.getSharedPreferences("SomePreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to Get SharedPreferences, and

```
pref.getString(), pref.getInt()..../
```

to get valuies from preferences.

and load these values to PreferenceActivity's components.

Comment: thnx!!!
thr ws a problm with my eclipse ws givin me errors bt restrd it n it gt fixed...

Answer (score 0):

The code should be pretty simple.

```
SharedPreferences sharedprefs = Context.getSharedPreferences(oldsharedprefs, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```